# How to make navbar go on body padding

Tags: html, css

I would like my nav to overlap the body padding and only it how to get it? I've seen similar questions but they didn't help me unfortunately.

CSS

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
body {
  font-family: "Anonymous Pro", monospace;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1, 7;
  color: #777;
  padding: 0 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  font-family: "lato";
  margin: 0;
}

.navigation {
  background-color: $primary-color;
  text-align: center;
  clear: both;
  height: 10vh;
  font-size: 25px;

  margin-bottom: 50px;

  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
  }
  a:hover {
    color: rgb(41, 175, 175);
  }
}
```

I would greatly appreciate your help and explaining to me how this " *{}" works.

Comment: Can you update this to a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, and describe specifically what problem you are referring to?

Comment: @David In simpler terms, my body is set to padding 30 and I want the navbar to ignore that padding and overlap it.

Comment: Are you just looking for `position: fixed;` then?  Or `position: absolute;` perhaps?

Comment: @David Unfortunately, none of the options helped to make the navbar overlap the body padding.

Answer (score 0):

Set the navbar to **'z-index:100,'** which will make the navbar go on top of any other elements that have a lower z-index. See the link below for examples and how to use it.

> [MDN Z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)